# How can I install angular-ui-router 1.xx with jspm

Tags: npm, angular-ui-router, jspm

NPM only has version 0.31 of angular-ui-router is there a way to install version 1.xx alpha via jspm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it.

```
> jspm install angular-ui-router=npm:angular-ui-router --edge
     Updating registry cache...
     Downloading npm:angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.1
ok   Installed angular-ui-router to npm:angular-ui-router@^1.0.0-beta.1 (1.0.0-beta.1)
     Install tree has no forks.

ok   Install complete.
```

Comment: Not a very good solution, it does not add `angular` dependency to it.